# Firebase Firestore how to add subcollection

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore

Hi I'm new to programming and have been working on a website using Firebase Firestore as my database.

I wanted to create a subcollection in my already existing collection ('Einkaufsliste') by using the document ID. But instead it creats a new document with a different document ID and a subcollection.
*Using a onClick methode to create the cart.*
*The counter is for checking if the current user ID already exists*

[image]

[image]

**Hier ist my JavaScript code**

```
function clickCart() {
var docID = '';
var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
console.log(counter)
if(counter < 1) {
    console.log('DocID: ' + docID);
    firebaseDatabase.collection('Einkaufsliste').doc().set({
        UserID: user.uid,
        UserName: user.displayName
    })
    .then(() => {
        console.log("%c Document successfully written!", 'color: green' );
        counter = counter + 1
    })
    firebaseDatabase.collection('Einkaufsliste').where('UserID', '==', user.uid).get()
    .then((snapshot) => {
        snapshot.docs.forEach(documentUserUi => {
            console.log('Function works!')
            console.log(documentUserUi.id);
            docID = documentUserUi.id;
            console.log('DocID: ' + docID);

        })
    })
    console.log("hier!")
    console.log('DocID: ' + docID);
    firebaseDatabase.collection('Einkaufsliste').doc(docID).collection('Warenkorb').doc().set({
        WarenkorbName: 'test'
    })

} else {
    console.log("%c User already exists and can't be added", "color: yellow")
    console.log(counter)

}
```

}

**Edit I think that I found the problem docID seems to be empty, but still need to test.
Also for some reason console.log('hier') output is earlier than the console.log('Funktion works!')**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.set()` accept an object as parameter and cannot be null. You would have provide a document ID as shown below:

```
firebaseDatabase.collection('Einkaufsliste').doc(docID).collection('Warenkorb').doc("someDocumentId").set({
        WarenkorbName: 'test'
    })
```

But if you are not concerned about document ID then you can use a random ID that firestore generates by using the `.add()` method:

```
firebaseDatabase.collection('Einkaufsliste').doc(docID).collection('Warenkorb').add({
        WarenkorbName: 'test'
    })
```

Comment: When using the .add() methode it throws a error:
Uncaught FirebaseError: Function CollectionReference.doc() cannot be called with an empty path.

Comment: @Sythous can you please add a screenshot of that error?

Comment: @Sythous it is `.collection("Warenkorb").add()` and not `.collection("Warenkorb").doc().add()`

Comment: Code:
        `firebaseDatabase.collection('Einkaufsliste').doc(docID).collection('Warenkorb').add({
            WarenkorbName: 'test'
        })`
Like this?
[link] (https://imgur.com/a/euL6Fo6)

Comment: @Sythous you have made the same mistake in multiple places. Please correct them. See this screen shot  https://imgur.com/3nuOo0G

Comment: `firebaseDatabase.collection('Einkaufsliste').add({
            UserID: user.uid,
            UserName: user.displayName
        })
 firebaseDatabase.collection('Einkaufsliste').doc(docID).collection('Warenkorb').add({
            WarenkorbName: 'test'
        })`
**Same result** [link] (https://imgur.com/yqHFhoF)

Comment: @Sythous can you please share what the variable firebaseDatabase looks like?

Comment: I found the problem and got it to work. I read "https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/async-await-javascript-tutorial/"this about asynchronous funktions. I think the problem was that due to the nature of how promises work, that my docID variable was empty bevor the function was passed to the browser and thats also the reason why I got this error. **Link to working code** https://imgur.com/3FapHnP 
I just added the .then() methode to wait until the fuction throws request succeeds

Answer (score 2):

For Firebase 9 here is an example that works :

```
import { db } from "../firebase"; // your local firebase.js
import { addDoc collection } from "firebase/firestore";

const docRef = await addDoc(
      collection(db, "users", "sadasdsdasas", "posts"),
      {
        description: "test Description",
        title: "Test",
      }
    );


console.log("Document written with ID: ", docRef.id);

details:
"users" => parentCollection
"sadasdsdasas" => parent collection id
"posts" => subCollection to into the user with the id "sadasdsdasas"
```

doc : https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/data-model